# Type safety in enum wrapper

Tags: java, android

Background info:

Sometimes you need to share a couple of global preferences in your android application and one option is to use the SharedPreferences to accomplish this;

```
//get the preferences

SharedPreferences prefs = myActivity().getSharedPreferences(“ConfigurationStore”, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//store a value

prefs.edit().putString(“user”, “Teddy”).commit();

//get the value

prefs.getString(“user”, null);
```

I like my code simple so I wrote a wrapper to hide the above, here is the result.

```
public enum ConfigurationStore {
  USER(“user”);
  private String key;
  private SharedPreferences prefs = //get this from your activity class
  ConfigurationStore(String key){
    this.key = key;
  }
  public String get(){
    return prefs.getString(key, null);
  }
  public void set(String value){
    prefs.edit().putString(key, value).commit();
  }

}
```

The usage of the wrapper is shown below

```
//Set a value:
ConfigurationStore.USER.set("Teddy");
//get a value
ConfigurationStore.USER.get()
```

It's easy to extend with new properties just by adding to the enum:

```
public enum ConfigurationStore {
  USER(“user”),
  DEPLOYMENT_TYPE(“deployment_type”);
....
//Set a value:
ConfigurationStore.DEPLOYMENT_TYPE.set("Beta-test");
//get a value
ConfigurationStore.DEPLOYMENT_TYPE.get()
```

The question:

The enum is strictly handing String properties. 
Is there a way I can make this enum handle different types safely without adding other method signatures (getStringValue, getIntValue)?

I want to be able to do something like:

```
int age = 23;
String name = "Teddy"
ConfigurattionStore.AGE.set(age)
ConfigurattionStore.NAME.set(name)
...
age = ConfigurattionStore.AGE.get();
name = ConfigurattionStore.NAME.get();
```

Comment: Enums are supposed to be a set of constants. You on the other hand seem to be using them as variables but with namespace. What's wrong with simple classes then?

Comment: It's easy to access form anywhere, no need to pass it along. Using enum as a way to implement singleton pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not with this design.

To be able to do what you want, you would need to define a generic interface or class

```
public PrefHandler<T> {
    T get();
    void set(T);
}
```

And have multiple instances of this interface:

```
public class ConfigurationStore {
    public static final PrefHandler<String> FOO = ...;
    public static final PrefHandler<Integer> BAR = ...;
}
```